# Ruby on Rails ignoring integer limit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I need to index a table of users using an externally sourced id, which is a 64-bit integer. Rails is perfectly capable of storing such a number, unless it's the primary key it seems. I have the following migration:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users, :id => false do |t|
      t.integer :id, limit: 8
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

The migration works fine, no errors reported, but when I attempt to seed it with a 64-bit integer, I'm told off by this:

```
RangeError: 76561198054432981 is out of range for ActiveRecord::Type::Integer with limit 4
```

Obviously Rails is ignoring the limit field, so long as it's the primary key/the :id field? How should I go about dealing with this?

For what it's worth I'm using sqlite3 (default), but to my knowledge, sqlite is perfectly capable of storing 64-bit integers.

Here's the table_info from sqlite:

```
0|id|integer(8)|0||0
1|name|varchar|0||0
2|created_at|datetime|1||0
3|updated_at|datetime|1||0
```

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a SQLite issue? http://jakegoulding.com/blog/2011/02/06/sqlite-64-bit-integers/

Comment: @CristianoBetta I don't believe so, I tried adding another column with the same specs under a different name which worked fine. According to pragma table_info both are defined in the same way.

Comment: I have a similar issue on PostgreSQL. The database states that the column is `bigint` and the column metadata states the limit of 8, but I get the error of `out of range for ActiveModel::Type::Integer with limit 4`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The limit value you gave is correct; it corresponds to `BIGINT` type
[image]
Make sure your migration is applied; open you database in some CLI or GUI software and verify the col-type

**Addition:**
Changing a column's length or datatype in a migration will invalidate the column as a primary key. Rather, creating an initializer that overrides the site's default primary key datatype should provide the behavior you're looking to implement:

```
# config/initializers/change_primary_key_datatype.rb
require 'active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter'
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter::NATIVE_DATABASE_TYPES[:primary_key] = "bigserial primary key"
```

---

This is what we would do for `PG` database; This is possible because of

[image]

---

however in the code base of `SQLite` there is

[image]

Comment: I removed the database, ran the migration, tried seeding it, and the error remains. sqlite shows the correct and expected :limit.

Comment: So there's no driver-agnostic way to change the size of the primary key?

Comment: Why include screen shots of text when you could have pasted in the text (and linked to [the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SQLite3Adapter.html)) with less effort?

Comment: @muistooshort :: I needed to highlight few words so I thought it would be better